# How to write twitter tweets to HDFS using Spark Streaming Java API

Tags: java, hadoop, twitter, apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("SparkTwitterHelloWorldExample");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(60000));
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey);
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret);
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken);
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret);
String[] filters = new String[] {"Narendra Modi"};
JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> twitterStream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc,filters);

// Without filter: Output text of all tweets
JavaDStream<String> statuses = twitterStream.map(
        new Function<Status, String>() {
            public String call(Status status) { return status.getText(); }
        }
);
statuses.print();
statuses.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://HadoopSystem-150s:8020/Spark_Twitter_out","txt");
```

I am able to fetch the Twitter tweets but I am getting error while writing to HDFS.

Can some one help me in saving the tweets to HDFS using Java

Here is the Error I am getting:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project SparkTwitterHelloWorldExample:
>   Compilation failure [ERROR]
>   /home/Hadoop/Mani/SparkTwitterHelloWorldExample-master/src/main/java/de/michaelgoettsche/SparkTwitterHelloWorldExample.java:[58,17]
>   cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol  : method
>   saveAsHadoopFiles(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) [ERROR] location:
>   class
>   org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream

Comment: please help me in saving the tweets to HDFS using spark streaming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use rather `saveAsTextFile()` method. Hadoop output formats are applicable only to `JavaPairDStream` (it requires *key* and *value*).

The solution is:

```java
statuses.dstream().saveAsTextFiles(prefix, suffix);
```

Comment: Thank you vanekjar, using statuses.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://HadoopSystem-150s:8020/hadoop_Twitter/tweets","txt"); iam writing to HDFS folder, Here each tweet is appending the time and writing. i.e

Comment: hadoop fs -ls /hadoop_Twitter/tweets-1442932338000.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup         85 2015-09-22 20:02 /hadoop_Twitter/tweets-1442932338000.txt/part-00000  and hadoop_Twitter/tweets-1442932338000.txt/part-00001 etc.. is there any way writing to a single file

Comment: I am not sure about appending one file from Spark Streaming. But you can use `FileUtil.copyMerge()` to merge all files in given directory to single file.

Comment: Hey does it also work with local file system? I am trying to do the same but its not writing... Can you help?

Comment: @Raj : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860730/wordcounts-dstream-saveastextfileslocal-file-system-path-txt-not-worki

Comment: @vanekjar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860730/wordcounts-dstream-saveastextfileslocal-file-system-path-txt-not-worki