# wordCounts.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("LOCAL FILE SYSTEM PATH", "txt"); does not write to file

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, pyspark, spark-streaming, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to write JavaPairRDD into file in local system. Code below:

```
 JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
  new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
      return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
    }
  }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
      return i1 + i2;
    }
  });
wordCounts.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("/home/laxmikant/Desktop/teppppp", "txt");
```

I am trying to save the logs or the wordcount in file. But it is not able to save in a local file (NOT HDFS).

I also tried to save on HDFS using

```
saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://10.42.0.1:54310/stream","txt")
```

The above line does not write to file. Can anybody tell the solution?
Various solutions on stackoverflow dont work.

Comment: _Does not work_ is not a good description of the problem.

Comment: @zero323 : Can you help with solution?

Comment: Could you please include the result of the command? As @zero323 says, *Does not work* doesn't give any concrete information.

Comment: @MikelUrkia : Its not writing to file . It is printing on terminal but not appending to file.

Comment: are you sure you are running that code and not something else?

Comment: @SebastianPiu : yes, it is printing the wordcount on terminal. just not writing to file.

Comment: no offense but when @Amensiac said it doesnt work and saveAsHadoopFiles() is the API then it is very intuitive that write to file didnt work. The emphasis should be to provide soln to a problem, which was not done here.

Answer (score 5):

Try to write output as an absolute path:

```
saveAsTextFiles("file:///home/laxmikant/Desktop/teppppp", "txt");
```

Comment: wordCounts.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("/home/laxmikant/Desktop/teppppp", "txt");  this is absolute local file path only.

Comment: I don't understand why it does not write. It prints output on terminal. But only not writing to file.

Comment: @Amnesiac Include the protocol `file:///` too.

Comment: same issue, all very odd

Answer (score 1):

```
rdd.saveAsTextFile("C:/Users/testUser/file.txt")
```

It will not save the data into the **file.txt** file. It will throw the **FileAlreadyExists Exception**. Because this method will create the own file and saves the rdd in that particular file.

Try to use the following code to save the rdd's in a file.

```
rdd.SaveAsTextFile("C:/Users/testUser")
```

It will create create a file under testUser folder and saves the rdd's into that file.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems to correct

```
saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://10.42.0.1:54310/stream","txt");
```

but the full syntax is

```
wordCounts.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://10.42.0.1:54310/stream","txt"); // no dstream()
```

My guess is that the data is somewhere stuck in some system buffer and is not getting written. If you try to stream a lot more data using "nc" then you may see a file with data being created. This is what happened in my case.